# Object Variable or With Block variable not set (error 91) Please assist

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to automate an email function for my team to use, I am also a rookie at doing this stuff so please forgive the basic coding here. I am getting the error 91 message Object Variable or With Block variable not set

Here is the code:

```
Sub Notification()  
  Dim outobj, mailobj
  Dim objUserPrmt1 As Object
  Dim strUserPrmt1
  Dim message, title, defaultValue As String

  message = "Enter your issue"
  title = "InputBox Demo"
  defaultValue = "No Issue"

  Set outobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set mailobj = outobj.CreateItem(0)
  Set strUserPrmt1 = objUserPrmt1.CreateItem(InputBox(message, title, defaultValue, 25, 45))

  With mailobj
    .To = "someone@somewhere.com"
    .Subject = "Notification:" strUserPrmt1
    .Body = "Test"
    '.Send
    .Display
  End With

  'Clear the memory
  Set outobj = Nothing
  Set mailobj = Nothing
  Set strUserPrmt1 = Nothing
  Set objUserPrmt1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hoping someone can show me where I have failed.

Comment: This is VBA rather than VBScript. objUserPrmt1 is used but never initialized.

Comment: Perhaps your issue is with `strUserPrmt1`. Declare it as a `string` and use `strUserPrmt1 = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue, 25, 45)`.

Comment: Not sure where I need to initialize, can you provide an example?

Comment: [Please remember to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you declared an object variable `objUserPrmt1` but you never set it equal to anything, hence it says at its default value of `Nothing`. Nevertheless, you tried to used this bit of nothing in the line:

```
Set strUserPrmt1 = objUserPrmt1.CreateItem(InputBox(message, title, defaultValue, 25, 45))
```

which is undoubtedly the line that threw the error (something which you should have been explicit about in the question).

You seem to be trying to use the `CreateItem` method of the Outlook object model. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220082(v=office.11).aspx) shows that this is a method of an `Application` object. Since you *already* have such an object (`outobj`) it isn't at all clear what possible purpose `objUserPrmt1` is supposed to have. Why not just use `outobj`?

Having said this, if you replace the problem line by:

```
Set strUserPrmt1 = outobj.CreateItem(InputBox(message, title, defaultValue, 25, 45))
```

you will probably still get an error (albeit not the same error). This is because the documentation I linked to says that the `CreateItem` method is expecting an `OlItemType constant` but you are passing it a string.

The `InputBox` returns a string, so I think that @AlexP is correct that what you want is probably simply:

```
strUserPrmt1 = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue, 25, 45)
```

Since a string isn't an object it doesn't need to be `Set` -- just assigned.

I would recommend simply deleting `objUserPrmt1` from your code. It doesn't have any reason for existence and is just causing your code to throw errors. Make sure that you also get rid of the two lines:

```
Set strUserPrmt1 = Nothing
Set objUserPrmt1 = Nothing
```

Also, it wouldn't hurt to declare `strUserPrmt1` as a string variable, although its current implicit declaration as a variant is adequate.

Comment: Thanks John, that worked to get around the error 91 issue.

Comment: Now I am getting a Run-time error 13 - Type mismatch when I try the following:  .Subject = "Notification: " And strUserPrmt1, any advice?

Comment: Never mind, sorry, I figured it out, I should be using the & instead of the word And